# Insert an element in end of a singly Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I have been trying to fix this code since morning but could get it done. So, finally i need some help in figuring out the error. The code compiles with no error but when i run it from terminal i get an error saying  "segmetation error: 11"

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 


struct Node{
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
};


struct Node *head; 


void Insert(int data); 
void Print();  


int main()
{
    head = NULL; //list is empty

    Insert(3); 
    Insert(5); 
    Insert(2); 
    Insert(8); 

    Print(); 

    return 0;  
} 


void Insert(int data) 
{
    struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    temp->data = data; 
    temp->next = NULL; 

    struct Node *temp1 = head;

    while(temp1 != NULL) 
    { 
        temp1= temp1->next; 
    } 

    temp1->next = temp; 
}


void Print()
{ 
    struct Node *temp =head; 

    while(temp != NULL)
    { 
        temp = temp->next; 
        printf("%d", temp->data); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Comment: `temp1->next = temp;` : `temp1` is `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually single linked lists have an inserting operation that inserts data at the beginning of the list. Nevertheless your function insert can look the following way

```
void Insert( int data ) 
{
    struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof( struct Node ) ); 
    temp->data = data; 
    temp->next = NULL; 

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        struct Node *current = head;
        while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;
        current->next = temp;
    }
}
```

It would be better if you check in the function whether the node was allocated.

Function Print also is wrong. It can look like

```
void Print( void )
{ 
    for ( struct Node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    { 
        printf( "%d ", current->data ); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You never set `head` to anything other than `NULL`.
2. (Even if you fix the above) `temp1` is guaranteed to be `NULL` by the time you get to `temp1->next = temp;`.

P.S. I don't think it's such a great practice to call you variables `temp`, `temp1` etc. From those names it is impossible to tell what their supposed function is.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing

```
while(temp1 != NULL)
```

Make it like this

```
while(temp1->next != NULL)
```

Here, temp1 points to null at the end of loop, and you are trying to add node after null i.e.

```
null->next =temp;
```

which must be throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node *curr;

void Insert(int data){
    struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next =NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
        curr = head = temp;
    else
        curr = curr->next = temp;
}

void Print(){
    struct Node *temp =head; 
    while(temp != NULL){ 
        printf("%d ", temp->data); 
        temp=temp->next; 
    } 
}
```